# How to use php/mysql for select and display data in multiple categories

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to create a table similar to the sporting tables. There are 8 group in this table. (A-H)
There are 4 teams for each group. I tried to select all the teams with the SQL code below, And sort them by group name

```
SELECT *
FROM teams
ORDER BY groupName
```

I want the results to be displayed in a panel that contains a  html table.
below code:

```
<?php
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
        <div class="flip">
            <h3>Group <?php echo($row['groupName']);?></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Team</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo($row['team_pos']); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo($row['teamName_Pr']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

But with every repetition of the while loop, the group name repeats for each team.
How can I display all the groups teams in a specific table?
Also, when I use GROUP BY instead of ORDER BY, only one team is displayed per group.

My connection method is mysqli.

Comment: Could you show some sample data and what's your expect result?

Comment: What do you want exactly? One groupName for 4 team? Then One table for each team OR one table for 4 team? Please provide some code / data so we can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to accumulate the rows by the `groupName`. Don't use `GROUP BY` as it will not return all rows.

```
<?php

//$result = ...

$groups = [];

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    @$groups[$row['groupName']][] = $row;
}

foreach ($groups as $groupName => $rows) {
?>
    <div class="flip">
        <h3>Group <?php echo($groupName);?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo($row['team_pos']); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo($row['teamName_Pr']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Btw, please consider using a template engine.

Comment: Thanks dear Dimitris Filippou. I have already tested it.
but in this case only one result is shown in per table